# <%=yield%> not working in named templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

<%=yield%> works perfectly if my template is called layouts/application.erb. However, if I change the template to something else, then the yield doesn't work. For instance, my controller method is

```
render :template=>'layouts/survey'
```

and the right template gets rendered, **but its yield method doesn't show the output of the current action's view. What simple thing am I missing?** I have also tried

```
render :action=>"index", :template=>"layouts/survey"
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want to be using `:template` and not `:layout`?

Comment: I'm going to give best answer to dmathieu, because he beat you to the punch and has 500 points only. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

By "template" you mean the layout apparently. Then the option isn't the good one. It's :layout

```
render :action => 'index', :layout => 'survey'
```

Comment: What would template be for, then?

Comment: This might help explain - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-actions-template-from-another-controller

Comment: Hmmm... I'll have to see the difference between :template=> and :action=>, then... thanks Andy.